# Sqoop export issue: parsing input data

Tags: oracle, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to use Sqoop to load files on HDFS into Oracle database:

Here is my input data:
Input data:

> 100|John|Miller|3.10
>
> 200|Sam|Madden|4.0

Here is the Sqoop command:

> sqoop export --connect
>   "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//host:port/service" --password
>   "pass" --username "user" --export-dir "/hdfs/path/"
>   --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-null-string '\N' --input-null-non-string '\N' --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --table "SCRATCHPAD" --columns ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,GPA

Here is the snippet of the error message that I see. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

> INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1469238174088_466114_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task
>   logs  at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)  at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1707)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data:
>   '200  Sam Madden  200.20'

Comment: looks like the input  '200 Sam Madden 200.20' doesn't have any pipe ( | ) delimiters.  You might try using --validate also

Comment: what is your oracle table structure?